# GUI For Full Screen Text Based Application

Tags: c#, python, winforms, user-interface, fullscreen

I'm making a text based program on python/C# (open for both languages), and it has to have a GUI. the program is always in full screen. I've tried wxpython (too complicated, spent 5 hours making 1 page, every object is 5-10 lines of code) and winforms (not optimal for full screen). I'm looking for something that would be optimal for full screen - text and objects will change their size according to the screen resolution, ext. any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)? It's designed to be independent of the monitor scaling and resolution and therefore works well in these types of scenarios.

Comment: No I haven't, ill try right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python Tkinter module. The entire IDLE editor that ships with Python was coded in Tkinter! Here is a basic skeleton of a GUI:

```
import tkinter as tk

class OOP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("My Title")
        height = self.win.winfo_screenheight()
        width = self.win.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.win.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
        self.win.resizable(False, False)
        self.create_widgets()

    def click_me(self):
        print("The button was pressed")

    def create_widgets(self):
        tk.Label(self.win, text="My GUI").pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        tk.Button(self.win, text="Click ME", command=self.click_me).pack(expand=1, fill='both')

app = OOP()
app.win.mainloop()
```

To me this seems like not that much code to make a GUI that resizes as the user drags it. You can also specify the geometry that it initializes with if you so choose!

Comment: Thank you, but you missed entirly my question. The application is full screen, it does not resize. I need a GUI module that handles the different screen resolutions, and act accordinly(resize the text and objects)

Comment: yes, these things are possible in tkinter. I didn't know I was supposed to develop your application for you? You can call `self.win.winfo()` (i think that's the method) to get screen size, and set `self.win.geometry("Some size relating to the window size")` to set it to be full-screen or somewhere in between. Finally, you can set the resizability to False as well and force it to always be fullscreen. Obviously a single forum post can't encompass the 100,000+ lines of code that the module consists of.

Comment: Well, I said that because Ive already tried tkinter, and I dis manage to get it to go full screen as you said, but the text is not resizing.

Comment: @RoBaMe well there you go! I edited in the 4 lines of code to make it full screen and not resizeable. Obviously with only a label and button present it looks like dogshit, but I think this showcases how easy it is to drastically change your GUI with just a few lines. You can see that I `.pack(expand=1, fill='both')` in order to get things to fill the available space. You can increase font size of text as well. I'm not sure what "text is not resizing" refers to